# Bootstrap Toggle Open Menu not spanning 100% width of screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having a bit of a problem with the Bootstrap nav I've placed on a website I'm making.

When collapsed on smaller screens, the drop down navigation menu doesn't span 100% of the screen - It looks as if there's a 1px gap on either side of the menu and I can't seem to figure out how to fix this.

** EDIT **

Due to bad markup in my original post - I've updated this (still having probelems, but this represents my problem better) at [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/yuxwh8cm/2/)

```
<div class="navbar navbar-custom">
<div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation">
        <span class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></span> Menu</button> 

        <span class="logo"> Logo</span>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigation">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#linkRemovedForNow">Book A Repair</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#howitworks">How it Works</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#testimonals">Testimonals</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a> </li>
            </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you recreate the issue in https://jsfiddle.net/yuxwh8cm/ ?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing on your example link. 

I've further noticed that it could be something wrong across all the media queries because it seems that the border-bottom properties almost "curve upwards" just before the end of the page.

Adding an extra class of Navbar-fixed-top straightens out the slight curves but my intention was to have a standard Nav and then affix on scroll so I'd like to avoid using navbar-fixed-top.

Border-radius: 0px; helped ever so slightly but there's still a gap.

Comment: The curve at the corner is caused by @media (min-width:768px){.navbar{border-radius:4px}} in the bootstrap.min.css. You can override that in your css, but I don't see the 1 pixel gap on smaller sizes.

Comment: It's hard to see the problem with the code you posted, and the markup has issues (extra and missing tags) Can you create an example to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what I managed to do with the markup to mess that up so bad. I've fixed it now and added a fiddle linked in the original edited post!

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because of the Bootstrap margin on the `.navbar-collapse`.. which is a negative margin of 15px. Just move it out a pixel on each side:

```
.navbar-custom .container >.navbar-collapse {
    margin-right: -16px;
    margin-left: -16px;
}
```

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/hsUB1MozL4)

Comment: Thank you!  I've updated this answer (being fairly new here,  it won't show just yet).

Comment: You updated the answer? Did you mean to say question?